# How to create a block of text that has a paragraph header?

Tags: formatting

[image]

Stumbled upon something like this in my textbook, and I am very curious as to how to recreate this effect, as it looks very clean. I tried \paragraph{heading} but I can't figure out a way to make the indentation right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `tabularx` for instance:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
    $\overline{\underline{\textsf{\bfseries PROOF STRATEGY}}}$ & 
    This result doesn't seem to fit into the kinds of results we've been proving. (This is not unusual. After learning how to prove certain statements, we encounter new statements that require us to ... think.) If we attempt to give either a direct proof or a proof by contrapositive of this result, we may be headed for difficulties. There is, however, another approach. Even though we must be very careful about what we are assuming, from what we know about even and odd integers, it appears that if $5x - 7$ is odd, then $x$ must be even. In fact. if we knew that whenever $5r - 7$ is odd then y is even. this fact would be extremely helpful. We illustrate this next. Don't forget that our goal is to prove the following result, which we will refer to as Result 3.14: Let $x\in\mathbb Z$. If $5x - 7$ is odd then $9x + 2$ is even. The (unusual) numbering of this result is because we will first state and prove a lemma (Lemma 3.13) that will aid us in the proof of Result 3.14.\hfill $\diamondsuit$   
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solution based on a list.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand\ruled[2]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{\sffamily\bfseries#1}%
  \sbox0{{\sffamily\bfseries#1}%
    \llap{\rule[-0.2\baselineskip]{\dimen0}{0.4pt}}%
    \llap{\rule[0.75\baselineskip]{\dimen0}{0.4pt}}}
  \begin{list}{}{
    \setlength\parsep{0pt}
    \setlength\labelwidth{\dimen0}
    \setlength\labelsep{1em}
    \setlength\listparindent{15pt}
    \setlength\leftmargin{\dimen0+1em}
  }%
    \item[\usebox0]#2\hfill$\blacklozenge$\par
  \end{list}
}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]
\ruled{PROOF STRATEGY}{\kant*[1]}
\ruled{PROOF}{\kant[1-2]\kant*[3]}
\kant[4][1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The indented paragraph can be done with `\hangindent`, which can go over pagbreaks and is reset by the next `\par`.

The heading can be done various ways; likewise the ruled lines.

Here, as a subsubparagraph, with the lines added as `\llap`ped `\rule`s as per @Celdor's answer:

[image: subsubpar]

As a `tabular`, with the lines coming in as `\hline`s (this also illustrates line-breaking of a long string):

[image: tabular]

Lines as `\overline` `\underline` in math mode (per Arne's solution):

[image: overlineunderline]

For variety, a `tcolorbox` vignette (default is a brown frame):

[image: vignette]

Plain TikZ is also a possible solution (for the lines, but also for everything), though likely a heavy one for such a straightforward requirement.

If a basic macro is used, and its arguments parameterized, a subsubparagraph heading can be the more easily altered (with simple code; code that eventually expands to a `\par` token inside a header will break).

Colour:

[image: color]

fcolorbox:

[image: fcolorbox]

Paragraph `\hangafter=` lines parameter can also vary.

Default setting for the macro is hangafter=0 (all lines)

[image: all lines]

hangafter=4; the space can be used for student notes, stamps or stickers.

[image: notes]

Same, with the heading pushed down the page (and\or the text pulled up).

[image: heading in space]

hangafter=-3 (the complement)

[image: negative hangafter]

Non-text can go in that spot, too, of course:

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % now in kernel
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{vignette}




% ------------------ heading
\newcommand\sphbeforeskipdefault{\baselineskip}
\newcommand\sphbeforeskip{\sphbeforeskipdefault}
\newcommand\setsphbeforeskip[1]{%
    \renewcommand\sphbeforeskip{#1}}

\newcommand\sphrightgapdefault{2em}
\newcommand\sphrightgap{\sphrightgapdefault}
\newcommand\setsphrightgap[1]{%
    \renewcommand\sphrightgap{#1}}




% ------------------ par
\newcommand\sphangafterdefault{0}
\newcommand\sphangafter{\sphangafterdefault}
\newcommand\setsphangafter[1]{%
    \renewcommand\sphangafter{#1}}


\newcommand\spvskipdefault{-1.8\baselineskip}
\newcommand\spvskip{\spvskipdefault}
\newcommand\setspvskip[1]{%
    \renewcommand\spvskip{#1}}
%-1.8\baselineskip

\newcommand\spindentdefault{\noindent}
\newcommand\spindent{\spindentdefault}
%\noindent

\newcommand\spvskipadjdefault{1.8}
\newcommand\spvskipadj{\spvskipadjdefault}
\newcommand\setspvskipadj[1]{%
    \renewcommand\spvskipadj{#1}}
%2.3



\ExplSyntaxOn


%****************************************************
%*
%****************************************************
%-------------------- \proofpar
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \proofpar { O{uppercase} m } {

        \renewcommand\sparstylehook{\csname #1\endcsname}

            \str_case:nnTF { #1 }
            {
                 { spnorule } { }
                 { spnrbox } { }
                 { spnrfcbox } { }
                 { spnrcustom } { }
            }       
                { %T
            \subsubparagraph{\xruled*{#2}}
                }
                { %F
            \subsubparagraph{\xruled{#2}}
            }

        \vskip\spvskip   %\vskip-1.8\baselineskip
        \spindent  %\noindent
        \hangindent=\g_tmpb_dim
        \hangafter=\sphangafter

}

%****************************************************
%*
%****************************************************
%-------------------- xRuled
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \xruled { s m } {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box    { \l_tmpa_tl  }
        \dim_gset:Nn \g_tmpb_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box + \sphrightgap }
        \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpb_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {
        \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn
                \l_tmpb_box
                { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
                { 
                    \l_tmpa_tl 
%                   \llap{\rule[-0.2\baselineskip]{\dim_use:N \l_tmpb_dim}{ 0.6pt }} 
%                   \llap{\rule[0.75\baselineskip]{\dim_use:N \l_tmpb_dim}{ 0.6pt }} 
                }
        }
        {
        \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn
                \l_tmpb_box
                { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
                { 
                    \l_tmpa_tl 
                    \llap{\rule[-0.2\baselineskip]{\dim_use:N \l_tmpb_dim}{ 0.6pt }} 
                    \llap{\rule[0.75\baselineskip]{\dim_use:N \l_tmpb_dim}{ 0.6pt }} 
                }
        }

        \box_use_drop:N
            \l_tmpb_box
}



%****************************************************
%*
%****************************************************
%-------------------- \boxpar
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \boxpar { m } {

        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box    { \l_tmpa_tl  }
        \dim_gset:Nn \g_tmpb_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box + \sphrightgap }
        \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpb_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
        \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \spvskipadj \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }% + \spvskipadj\baselineskip }
        \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn
                \l_tmpb_box
                { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
                { 
                    \l_tmpa_tl 

                }

        \box_use_drop:N
            \l_tmpb_box
        
        \vskip-\l_tmpa_dim %\spvskip   %\vskip-1.8\baselineskip
        \spindent  %\noindent
        \hangindent=\g_tmpb_dim
        \hangafter=\sphangafter

}







\ExplSyntaxOff



% ------------------ heading style

\newcommand{\sparstylehook}{}
\newcommand{\spnop}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\spblue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\newcommand{\spbox}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
\newcommand{\spfcbox}[1]{\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{#1}}

\newcommand{\spnorule}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\spnrbox}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
\newcommand{\spnrfcbox}[1]{\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow!50}{#1}}
\newcommand{\spnrcustom}[1]{%
#1%
}
\newcommand{\sptable}[1]{%
#1%
}



\makeatletter
%
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]% counter for numbering
\renewcommand{\thesubsubparagraph}% how to display
{\thesubparagraph.\@Alph\c@subsubparagraph}% numbering
\newcommand{\subsubparagraph}{\@startsection
{subsubparagraph}%
{6}% [level]
{0em}% [indent]
{\sphbeforeskip}% [beforeskip]
{1pt}% [afterskip]
{\sffamily\large\bfseries\sparstylehook}}% [style]
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{7}{12em}{5em}}% for toc
\newcommand{\subsubparagraphmark}[1]{}% for page headers
\makeatother
%







\newcommand\texta{The cat sat on the mat and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\ }
\newcommand\textb{\texta\texta}
\newcommand\textc{\textb\textb}
\newcommand\textd{\textc\textc\textc\hfill$\diamondsuit$\par\textb}


\begin{document}


\section{section}
xxx
\subsection{subsection}
xxx
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
xxx
\paragraph{paragraph}
xxx
\subparagraph{subparagraph}
xxx



\proofpar{proof strategy}
1: \textc


yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy 

\proofpar{proof}
yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy 


\proofpar{A Voyage to Arcturus}
2: \textc\textc\textc\par\textb


{ 
\setsphangafter{4}
\setspvskip{0.5\baselineskip}
\proofpar{A Voyage to Arcturus}
3: hangafter=4; vskip 0.5 baselineskip \textc\textc\textc\par\textb
}

{ 
\setsphbeforeskip{5\baselineskip}
\setspvskip{-5.5\baselineskip}
\setsphangafter{3}
\proofpar{A Voyage to Arcturus}
4: sphbeforeskip=5 baselineskip ; sphangafter=3, spvskip -5.5 baselineskip  \textc\textc\textc\par\textb
}


{ 
\setsphangafter{-3}
\proofpar{A Voyage to Arcturus}
5:  sphangafter=-3  
\textc\textc\textc\par\textb
}






 

\proofpar{A Voyage to Arcturus}
6: default \textd


\proofpar[spnorule]{A Voyage to Arcturus}
7: spnorule \textd


\proofpar[spnop]{A Voyage to Arcturus}
8: spnop \textd


\proofpar[spblue]{A Voyage to Arcturus}
9: spblue \textd

{
\setsphrightgap{3em}
\proofpar[spnrbox]{A Voyage to Arcturus}
10: spnrbox \textd
}

{
\setsphrightgap{3em}
\proofpar[spnrfcbox]{A Voyage to Arcturus}
11: spnrfcbox \textd
}


{
\setspvskip{-3.8\baselineskip}
\proofpar[spnrcustom]{\hbox{\begin{tabular}{c}A Voyage\\ to\\ Arcturus\\\end{tabular}}}
12: spnrcustom = tabular \textd
}

{
\setspvskip{-4.8\baselineskip}
\proofpar[spnrcustom]{\colorbox{blue!10}{\begin{tabular}{c}A Voyage\\ to\\ Arcturus\\\end{tabular}}}
13: spnrcustom = cb tabular \textd
}


{
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[draw,fill=blue!60] (A) {%
\colorbox{blue!10}{\begin{tabular}{c}A Voyage\\ to\\ Arcturus\\\end{tabular}}%
};%
\tcbvignette{outside node=A}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
%}}
        \vskip-5.2\baselineskip
        \noindent
        \hangindent=1.5in
        \hangafter=0
14: tcolorbox vignette \textd
}




{
%\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\boxpar{\colorbox{blue!10}{\begin{tabular}{c}\hline\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}A Voyage\\to\\ Arcturus\\\hline \end{tabular}}}
15: boxpar cb tabular \textd
}


{
\vspace{2\baselineskip}%
\setspvskipadj{2.3}%
\boxpar{\colorbox{blue!10}{\sffamily\large\bfseries\begin{tabular}{c}\hline\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}\MakeUppercase{A Voyage}\\\MakeUppercase{to}\\\MakeUppercase{Arcturus}\\\hline \end{tabular}}%
}
16: boxpar cb + fonts + tabular \textd
}


{
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\setspvskipadj{1.3}%
\boxpar{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[draw,fill=blue!60] (A) {%
\colorbox{blue!10}{\begin{tabular}{c}A Voyage\\ to\\ Arcturus\\\end{tabular}}%
};%
\tcbvignette{outside node=A}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
17: boxpar tcolorbox vignette \textd
}





{
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\setspvskipadj{1.3}%
\boxpar{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[draw,fill=blue!60] (A) {{\sffamily\large\bfseries%
\colorbox{blue!10}{\begin{tabular}{c}A Voyage\\ to\\ Arcturus\\\end{tabular}}%
}};%
\tcbvignette{outside node=A}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
18: boxpar tcolorbox vignette \textd
}


{
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\setspvskipadj{1.3}%
\boxpar{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[draw,fill=blue!60] (A) {{\sffamily\large\bfseries%
\colorbox{blue!10}{\begin{tabular}{c}\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}\MakeUppercase{A Voyage}\\\MakeUppercase{to}\\\MakeUppercase{Arcturus}\\\end{tabular}}%
}};%
\tcbvignette{outside node=A}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
19: boxpar tcolorbox vignette \textd
}





{
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\setspvskipadj{1.1}%
\boxpar{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[draw,fill=blue!60] (A) {{\sffamily\large\bfseries%
\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-duck-portrait}%
}};%
\tcbvignette{outside node=A}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
20: boxpar tcolorbox vignette image \textd
}



{
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\setspvskipadj{1.1}%
\boxpar{%
\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-duck}%
}
21: boxpar image \textd
}



{
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
{\large\bfseries$\overline{\rule{0pt}{2.1ex}\underline{\textsf{PROOF STRATEGY}}}$}
        \vskip-1.8\baselineskip
        \noindent
        \hangindent=2in
        \hangafter=0
22: manual overline underline \textd
}


{
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\proofpar[spnrcustom]{\hbox{{$\overline{\rule{0pt}{2.1ex}\underline{\textsf{PROOF STRATEGY}}}$}}}
%       \vskip-1.8\baselineskip
%       \noindent
%       \hangindent=2in
%       \hangafter=0
23: auto overline underline \textd
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can coerce the standard `proof` environment of `amsthm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newlength{\modproofwd}
\newenvironment{modproof}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\modproofwd}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
  \begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=\dimexpr\modproofwd+1em\relax}\item\relax
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\blacklozenge}}%
  \begin{proof}[\makeheader{#1}]\hspace*{-\labelsep}\ignorespaces
}{\end{proof}\end{list}}
\newcommand{\makeheader}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \parbox[t]{\modproofwd}{%
      \parbox[b]{\modproofwd}{%
        \hrule\vspace{2pt}
        \normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}
      }%
      \vspace{2pt}\hrule
    }%
    \quad
  }\spacefactor=3000 % so proof doesn't add a period
}

\begin{document}

\kant[1][1-3]

\begin{modproof}{Proof Strategy}
\kant*[2][1-2]
\end{modproof}

\kant[3][1-3]

\begin{modproof}{Proof Strategy}
\kant*[2][1-3]
\end{modproof}

\kant[5][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]